# Is there a tool to extract a file from a ZIP archive when that file is not present in central directory but has its own LFH?

Tags: stream, zip, unzip

I'm looking for a tool that can extract files by searching aggressively through a ZIP archive. The compressed files are preceded with LFHs but no CDHs are present. Unzip outputs an empty folder.
I found one called 'binwalk' but even though it finds the hidden files inside ZIP archives it seems not to know how to extract them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [sunzip](https://github.com/madler/sunzip). It reads the zip file as a stream, and will extract files as it encounters the local headers and compressed data.

Use the `-r` option to retain the files decompressed in the event of an error. You will be left with a temporary directory starting with `_z` containing the extracted files, but with temporary, random names.